# retrofit 2 multipart send only array file instead of part with array

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm trying to send a POST using multipart/form-data. I faced some problems, which were resolved at this forum, like extra quotes and how to send several files. But now, I would like to send my files with unique names inside of one array. I will attach two files to express better what I want to do.

I'm receiving the files like this ...

[image: wrong structure]

and I want to receive my files like this ...

[image: correct structure]

is it possible to change the body data structure using retrofit 2? I would like to change the mimetype data from multipart/form-data to image/jpeg.

Some code

```
HashMap<String, RequestBody> files = attachFile();

    api.createPlant(plant.getName(),
            plant.getSize(), plant.getPhSoil(), plant.getEcSoil(), plant.getGardenId(), files)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Plant>() {
                @Override
                public final void onCompleted() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "on completed");
                }

                @Override
                public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public final void onNext(Plant response) {
                    mBody.setText(response.toString());
                }
            });

private HashMap<String, RequestBody> attachFile() {

    ArrayList<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfNames.add("images");
    listOfNames.add("mango-lg2");

    HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>(listOfNames.size());
    RequestBody file = null;
    File f = null;

    for(int i = 0, size = listOfNames.size(); i<size;i++){

        try {

            File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

            f = new File(folder, listOfNames.get(i) + ".jpg");

            Bitmap bitmap = convertFileToBitmap(f);

            if(bitmap != null){
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            }else{
                Log.i("INFO", "imageNotFound");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), f);
        map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + listOfNames.get(i) + ".jpg",file);
        file = null;
        f = null;
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using MultipartBody.Builder and I send the data using a RequestBody.

```
MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("name", plant.getName())
            .addFormDataPart("size", String.valueOf(plant.getSize()));

    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

    File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    files.add(new File(folder, "images.jpg"));
    files.add(new File(folder, "mango-lg2.jpg"));

    builder = addImagesToRequestBody(builder, files);

    api.createPlant(builder.build())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Plant>() {
                @Override
                public final void onCompleted() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "on completed");
                }

                @Override
                public final void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public final void onNext(Plant response) {
                    mBody.setText(response.toString());
                }
            });
```

Helper methods

```
private MultipartBody.Builder addImagesToRequestBody(MultipartBody.Builder builder, ArrayList<File> files){

    for(int i = 0, size = files.size(); i<size;i++){
        String mediaType = "image/" + getMediaType(files.get(i));
        RequestBody image = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mediaType), files.get(i));
        builder.addFormDataPart(files.get(i).getName(), files.get(i).getName(), image);
    }

    return builder;
}

private String getMediaType(File file) {
    return file.getAbsolutePath().split("\\.")[1];
}
```